# Prevent copying SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I am wondering if I can lock down an SSRS report that I have built so the user cannot copy it and set it up on another server.

Maybe some custom code to only run the report based on some server specific information?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the predefined security roles in SSRS. If you only give them `Browser` access to the report server they shouldn't be able to download the report definition file.

The only permissions that the `Browser` role has are:

- View Reports (run a report and view the report properties)
- View resources (view resources and resource properties)(
- View folders (view and navigate folders)
- View models
- Manage individual subscriptions (they can create and manage their own subscriptions)

Source: (MSDN - SSRS Predefined Roles) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363(v=sql.110).aspx#bkmk_browser

More info about SSRS role definitions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159820(v=sql.110).aspx